# Can anyone tell where the carat is defined in this HTML/CSS/jQuery menu example?

Tags: html, css

http://fiddle.jshell.net/#&togetherjs=o0KAAUEr6p

The carat right after "product" which indicates a dropdown list.
I could not find where it is referenced. 
In CSS, ...::after has content:"" which is confusing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The little `v` to the right of "PRODUCTS" is actually a combination of a `border-right` and `border-bottom` rotated by 45 degrees in `#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after`.

Comment: Yes, I see. It;s a small box with two borders shown. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer has solved your problem, please click the little checkmark to accept it.